# Code not work : how to disable the link when the cursor on

Tags: html, css, joomla, joomla3.2

May I know what's the problem with this code? I'd try to run it in my index.php in on of joomla module, but the site output is just white.

> echo ' < a style="cursor: pointer;" >onclick="location.href='http://example.com/index.php' ">Admin  < /a>';

I'd like to make the link for the **example.com/index.php** not appear / disabled when I put the cursor on the link. I'd try run the code above at the **Try It!** on **w3school.com** and it works perfectly, but if I put the code in my file in joomla module, it's not work!

Hope somebody could help me.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your code

```
echo ' < a style="cursor: pointer;" >onclick="location.href='http://example.com/index.php' ">Admin < /a>';
```

The Error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'http' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in index.php on line 7
```

- indentation of element `< a>` is not correct and should be `<a>` also applies with the closing tag `</a>`
- you have an excess `>` character near the `style="cursor: pointer;"`
- Use `window.location.href` instead of `location.href` because you are trying to return the url of the current page.
- Learn to escape characters as much as possible e.g `\"`

The correct php code.

- `echo "<a style='cursor: pointer;' onclick='window.location.href=\"http://example.com/index.php\"'>Admin</a>";`

Comment: No problem. Just keep in mind the correct syntax when making scripts and codes